# Business rules for identifing a junction table in T-SQL?

Tags: database, t-sql

Good morning stackoverflow users,

I'm looking for sketch some general business rules in order to create a query for finding all junction table, contained in a schema ( querying sys objects ).

Can you give some rules to acheive this please?

Actually i've released that:

- Junction table must have more than one constraint key.
- Junction table must have a primary key that are not pointed by any one (???).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear definition of a junction table. If you want to use just the rules you mentioned, then try the following query:

```
SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE fk.referenced_object_id=t.object_id)
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE fk.parent_object_id=t.object_id)>1
```

If you want to use a more complex definition, depending also on your particular coding conventions, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id), t.name FROM sys.tables t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE fk.referenced_object_id=t.object_id)
AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE fk.parent_object_id=t.object_id
    /* AND fk.name NOT LIKE '%CreateEmployeeID'AND fk.name NOT LIKE '%ModifyEmployeeID'*/
)=2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id=t.object_id
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        WHERE fkc.parent_object_id=c.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id=c.column_id
    ) AND c.column_id NOT IN (
        SELECT MIN(ic.index_column_id) FROM sys.indexes i
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
        WHERE i.object_id=c.object_id AND i.is_unique=1 GROUP BY i.index_id HAVING COUNT(*)=1
    ) /*AND c.name NOT IN ('CreateDate','CreateEmployeeID','ModifyDate','ModifyEmployeeID','rowversion')*/
)
/*AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
    WHERE i.object_id=t.object_id AND i.is_unique=1
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        WHERE fkc.parent_object_id=ic.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id=ic.column_id
    )
)*/
```

This query searches for tables that meet the following conditions:

- no other table references this table
- the table contains exactly two foreign keys
- the table contains no other column except those involved in the foreign keys and the unique key column (actually, it excepts all the columns that are part of any unique index on a single column)

Optionally, you could also check that the columns involved in the foreign keys are part of a unique index and you could add a few exceptions depending on your coding conventions.